# Move Minecraft world from one PS4 to another

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

I've got a nice Minecraft world on my friend's PS4, but I want to continue with the same world on my own system. Am I able to copy it and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @G.Eiwell Nope, it's not. It's a possessive form. But thanks for your critical input :)

Comment: @Joachim Aye, you're right... ':D

Comment: Whose account did you play under, yours or your friend's?

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft for PlayStation consoles isn't directly developed by Mojang, the ports were taken care of by *4J Studios*. As part of this distinction they will refer you to PlayStation support for  something like this.

For non-PlayStation platforms this official help site [explains](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034754892-Transferring-Minecraft-worlds-to-another-device-) how to do this using a free trial for *Minecraft Realms*, which feels like a weird workaround. But last I checked *Minecraft Realms* wasn't available for the PS4 version to begin with.

Slightly more promising is this article that explains how to migrate your PS3 *Minecraft* save to a PS4/Vita, that **might** be able to help you: [(click)](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131711-Transfer-from-PS3-to-PS4-Vita-)

I've also added the listed steps below:

While on your PlayStation 3:

- Start Minecraft and press Play Game
- In the list of your saved worlds, scroll down to the world you want to transfer
- Select a world and press R1 to open the save options
- Choose the alternative Upload save for PS Vita/PS4
- Wait for the upload to be completed and press OK when you’re given the option

When you've performed those steps on your PlayStation 3, start your PlayStation 4 or PlayStation Vita and do the following:

- Open Minecraft and click Play Game
- When in the game menu press the square to download your uploaded world
- Wait for the download to complete and click OK

You obviously don't want to transfer your world from a PS3 but instead from a PS4 to a different PS4, but it still might be worth looking around to see if this export option is available.

Good luck!