# Move minecraft world from ps4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

My 2 sons now have a ps4 each. Son number 2 started a Minecraft world on the original ps4. He now has a ps4 of his own. How do I move the world he has created from the old ps4 to the new ps4? He has the same 'account' and we've bought Minecraft again for this console and thought the world would be there when he signed in but it's not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move Minecraft world from one PS4 to another](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359757/move-minecraft-world-from-one-ps4-to-another)

Comment: That question was for the legacy console edition, whereas this one is for bedrock.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the official method**

Yes, you can transfer game save data from one PS4 to another. You will have to connect both PS4's with a wired LAN cable, navigate to "Settings" > "System" > "Transfer data from another PS4" and follow the instructions. Also see https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/transfer.html for a highly detailed explanation of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your help - will this transfer everything from the original ps4 to the new ps4?